# getting "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority" when running fiddler

Tags: wcf, fiddler, x509certificate

I have a WCF client application that sends a https request to a third-party webservice. everythings works well. I receive the correct answer.

I have installed fiddler and trusted its rootcertificate to capture and encode the https traffic. But now my requests recieve the error "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure..."

I have searched a lot on this error on the web. But each time the solution is that I need to trust the fiddler root certificate. Since I have done this from het start, it looks like this is not the solution for my problem.

Here is a snippet out of my code that sends the request:

```
AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement securityBindingElement = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
securityBindingElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
securityBindingElement.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509securityTokenParameters();
securityBindingElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
securityBindingElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());

CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(securityBindingElement, new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8), new HttpsTransportBindingElement());

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(URL), new X509CertificateEndpointIdentity(serverCertificate));

ChannelFactory<type> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<type>(binding, endpoint);
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = clientX509Certificaat;
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
channelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign;

type client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
client.request();
```

Somebody knows what is what is going wrong here?

Comment: I removed the endpoint identity when creating the endpointaddress and assigned the server certificate to the defaultcertificate of channelfactory.ServiceCertificate and the problem was solved. It is not clear for me why is is working now. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code to:

```
AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement securityBindingElement = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
securityBindingElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
securityBindingElement.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509securityTokenParameters();
securityBindingElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
securityBindingElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());

CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(securityBindingElement, new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8), new HttpsTransportBindingElement());

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(URL));

ChannelFactory<type> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<type>(binding, endpoint);
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = clientX509Certificaat;
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = serverX509Certificaat;
channelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign;

type client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
client.request();
```

It is not clear for me why I do not have problems anymore. Anyone?

Comment: ClientCertificates cannot pass through MITM interceptors like Fiddler; to allow a client certificate to be used against a server, Fiddler must be configured to use that certificate itself. See http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsclientcerts.asp